# Download csv file from link with java

Tags: java, csv

I'm creating a csv file with data saved to it. The next thing i wanna do is that any person can download that file from a link in a HTML page.

The problem is I've never worked before with Java and I've searched for some good options but non of them seems to work. I hope any one can help me with this.

This is how is save to my CSV file

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class Logbook {

    public Logbook() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * @param date
     * @param memoryMax
     * @param memoryCommitted
     * @param memoryUsed
     * @param JvmUpTimeH
     * @param JvmUpTimeD
     * @param JvmUpTimeM
     * @param JvmUpTimeS
     */
    public void writeLog(String date, Long memoryMax, Long memoryCommitted, Long memoryUsed, String TotalTime) {

        File Logbook = new File("C:/Logbook/Logbook.csv");

        try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(Logbook, true)))) {
            out.println(date + " , " + memoryMax + " b" + " , " + memoryCommitted + " b" + " , " + memoryUsed + " b" + " , " + TotalTime);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // exception handling left as an exercise for the reader
        }
    }


    }
```

After this I have a new page were it refreshes the page every sec my code to write it in the file is here

```
Long memoryUsed=agent.readMemoryUsed();
Long memoryCommitted=agent.readMemoryCommitted();
Long memoryMax=agent.readMemoryMax();
Date today2 = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat savedLog = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YY kk:mm:ss");
String date = savedLog.format(today2);

Logbook logBook = new Logbook();
logBook.writeLog(date, memoryMax,memoryCommitted,memoryUsed, TotalTime);
```

All I want now is to download the file with that information into it for any person that wanna download it.

Comment: put the file somewhere where it will be served by your webserver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to address this is to write the file to a location under your web server's file directory. You can serve this file statically - you don't need it to go through a webapp to provide it.

You don't mention what web server you're using, or even if you're using an application server on top of it, so we really can't help you that much more. If your question is actually about how to setup a web server - that gets beyond the scope of StackOverflow.